# Unable to fetch port count on nagios

Tags: nagios

I have formed a command for fetching established port connection using nagios check_by_ssh module. 
I am able to get the output when I run the command, however after placing the command in the commands.cfg file I am seeing "check_by_ssh: skip-stderr argument must be an integer " in the GUI. 
Any suggestion on this would be of great help.

```
Command:
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_by_ssh -l fuseadmin -H <hostname> -C "netstat -punta | grep -i ESTABLISHED | wc -l | awk '{if (\$0>2500) {print \"CRITICAL: Established Socket Count: \"\$0} else {print \"OK: Established Socket Count: \"\$0}}'" -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa -E

OK: Established Socket Count: 67
```

```
Commands.cfg:
define command {
      command_name    netstat_cnt_estanblished_gt_2500_fuse01
      command_line   /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_by_ssh -l fuseadmin -H a0110pcsgesb01 -C "netstat -punta | grep -i ESTABLISHED | wc -l 2>&1 | awk '{if (\$0>2500) {print \"CRITICAL: Established Socket Count: \"\$0} else {print \"OK: Established Socket Count: \"\$0}}'" -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa -E
}
```

```
Service Definition
#netstat_cnt_estanblished_gt_2500_csg2.0

define service{
        use                             generic-service         ; Name of service template to use
        host_name                       <hostname>
        service_description             Netstat Established Count
                event_handler                   send-service-trap-fms
        event_handler_enabled           1
        check_command                   netstat_cnt_estanblished_gt_2500_fuse01
        max_check_attempts              1
        notifications_enabled           1                      ; Service notifications are enabled
        check_period                    24x7                    ; The service can be checked at any time of the day
        max_check_attempts              3                       ; Re-check the service up to 3 times in order to determine its final (hard) state
        check_interval           2                     ; Check the service every 10 minutes under normal conditions
        retry_interval            2                     ; Re-check the service every two minutes until a hard state can be determined
        contact_groups                  fuse_users                  ; Notifications get sent out to everyone in the 'admins' group
        notification_options            w,u,c,r                 ; Send notifications about warning, unknown, critical, and recovery events
        notification_interval           30                      ; Re-notify about service problems every hour
        notification_period             24x7

       }
```

**I have changed the actual hostname to  due to compliance

Comment: Better approach is write own shell/bash script and put it on remote hosts. Then you should run it via check_by_ssh command on Nagios server.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://github.com/monitoring-plugins/monitoring-plugins/commit/3a12034805caf6c4ad21a8f86c8e4a43ff62576c) it says:

```
 check_by_ssh: print command output in verbose mode

right now it is not possible to print the command output of ssh. check_by_ssh
only prints the command itself. This patchs adds printing the output too. This
makes it possible to use ssh with verbose logging which helps debuging any
connection, key or other ssh problems.
Note: you must use -E,--skip-stderr=<high number>, otherwise check_by_ssh would
always exit with unknown state.

Example:

  ./check_by_ssh -H localhost -o LogLevel=DEBUG3 -C "sleep 1" -E 999 -v
```

**Meaning**: you should just have to specify a number after "-E", like `-E 999`, in your definition (like the example in above code-block says)

... even though, it's confusing (maybe a bug?), because the command help of `check_by_ssh` says:

```
-E, --skip-stderr[=n]
    Ignore all or (if specified) first n lines on STDERR [optional]
```